# Controlling space between lines or rows in tables using papaja with r markdown for pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, papaja

I'm working on APA tables with the package papaja and r markdown together with Latex and I want to adjust the vertical space between rows in a relatively big table so it will fit on one page. Additionally, if needed, i also want to reduce font size and column width. Is this possible with papaja's `apa_table()` function? Just using the `small` argument to `TRUE` did not do the trick.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, could you give a reproducible example (feel free to mention me)?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`papaja` manual](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/tips-and-tricks.html#adjusting-line-spacing) you can adjust line spacing in tables by adding some lines to the document preamble. The following will result in single-spaced tables with double-spaced caption and table note:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{lltable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\doublespacing}
  - \captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1.5}}
  - \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1.5}}
```

The column width is currently not controllable with `apa_table()` but you can use `landscape = TRUE` if the table doesn't fit in portrait mode. Font size can currently only be adjusted with `small = TRUE`.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the size, not spacing of tablenotes?
- \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\tiny}
did not it for me

Comment: I think this would be good separate question. ;)